# How can I create a persistent array var in PHP?

Tags: php, web-applications, superglobals

I'm writing a web application in PHP and I want to declare an array, in which i want to save the host and how often this host has opened my web application. I want to add the variable to something like the application scope in JSP. I've tried to add this array to $_SERVER, but this hasn't worked. If I try to acess the variable in another file with $_SERVER[$_GET["id"]] the variable is always NULL. Can someone please help me?

Here my code:

```
if(empty($_SERVER[$_GET["id"]])){
  $_SERVER[$_GET["id"]]=array($country, 1);
}else{
  $_SERVER[$_GET["id"]][$country]+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

several things:

1. $_SERVER is for SERVER do not use it to play global array.
2. $_SESSION is returning null because you probably didn't declare any
   session_start at the beginning of your file. If you don't do that, the session cookies (variables) are not shared and this is why its null.

this is the basic of vanilla php.

From here, you could explore a micro framework that has this built in...

**UPDATE**

due to your misconception of "session", what you want to do is to persist data. If you want to "share" this array of yours among different users (aka data sharing among session), I would recommend to persist via data storage:

- sqlite/memory or sqlite/file
- redis (value/key and its quick)
- mysql or any sql/no-sql
- least favorable IMO: write to a simple file and retrieve. The only issue with this, is that you will have "lock" condition but then again so will the other ones

Comment: $_Session was an error in my question. I used $_Server. Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my question. I want to make this array accessible for every user, not only in the actual session.

Comment: @holzfeli please rephrase your question